# Add picture to wall post using Facebook SDK 3.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a message on my wall, adding a PNG image (*not* a URL), as shown below. Everything works except that no image is posted. Is this even supported? Is there a size limit?

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
params.putString("description", message);
params.putString("caption", caption);
params.putString("name", name);
params.putString("link", link);

// Does not work:
// params.putByteArray("photo", pngByteArray);
// params.putByteArray("picture", pngByteArray);

WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
   Session.getActiveSession(),
   params)) /* ... */
```

As you can see, I'm using the `FeedDialogBuilder` class to let the user confirm the wall post.

Comment: what are you getting in response with sending byteArray code as a "picture" parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
params.putString("description", message);
params.putString("caption", caption);
params.putString("name", name);
bundle.putByteArray("picture", byte);
String response = facebook.request("me/photos",bundle,"POST");
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: Does that fire up the confirmation dialog? (See `FeedDialogBuilder`)

Comment: Also, that API is deprecated... :/

Comment: it is not in my case...i have used it in after making user authenticated and then this code makes its magic...

Answer (score 0):

You need one more field in it,

params.putString("app_id", "Your_App_ID_Required");

it worked for me after I added this field..